# Filter 2 arrays with object in php

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, codeigniter-3

I write a reservation system for rooms in a hotel.
I have one table in the database with all the rooms in the hotel (rooms). The next table is reservations. I need to write a function to which I will be given a date, start and end time of the reservation, and that this function would return all free rooms to me within the given time limit. I do not know how to bite it completely. Could someone guide me?

I was thinking about get all the rooms, then all the reservations, with the shipment to the function date, but what next? How to arrange it all?

@edit

Rooms table:

```
- id
- number
```

Reservation table:

```
- id
- room_id
- date
- time_start
- time_finish
```

Comment: I think you can do this all with a simple joined sql query. Can you share sample table data?

Comment: I added structure of tables

Comment: This better done in SQL and not php function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select rooms.* from rooms
left join reservations 
on rooms.id = reservations.room_id
and reservations.date = '2019-05-28' and reservations.time_start < '14:00' and reservations.time_finish > '14:00'
where reservations.id is null
```

If the test schema is like:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

CREATE TABLE `reservations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `room_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time_start` time NOT NULL,
  `time_finish` time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `reservations` (`id`, `room_id`, `date`, `time_start`, `time_finish`) VALUES
(0, 2,  '2019-05-28',   '13:00:00', '16:00:00');

CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `rooms` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'room1'),
(2, 'room2');
```

Fiddle example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f82a5c/1

Comment: I rewrote your code for CodeIgniter syntax: `$query = $this->db->join('reservations', 'rooms.id = reservations.room_id', 'left')
            ->where('reservations.id IS NULL', null, false)
            ->where('reservations.date', $date)
            ->where('reservations.time_start<=', $time_start)
            ->where('reservations.time_finish>=', $time_finish)
            ->get('rooms');`. My reservations table is empty so $query result should return all rooms but is empty too :(

Comment: I don't really know codeigniter, but you should have the reservations.date and time_start/time_finish parts all in the join. In the where clause should go only the reservations.id is null part.

Try something like this:
`$query = $this->db->join('reservations', "rooms.id = reservations.room_id and reservations.date = '{$date}' and reservations.time_start<= '{$time_start}' and reservations.time_finish>='{$time_finish}'", 'left') ->where('reservations.id IS NULL', null, false)->get('rooms');`